# Get GKPlayer.playerID from GKCloudPlayer.playerID

Tags: game-center, ios10, gkgamesession

I want to use new class GKGameSession in my iOS 10 multiplayer game. I need to get the `playerID` of all users from Game Center to check compatibility with previous versions of my game. But `GKPlayer.playerID != GKCloudPlayer.playerID`

How can I get `GKPlayer.playerID` from `GKCloudPlayer.playerID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to do this. They metioned this in the last WWDC.

> GKCloudPlayer is only for, to be used for Sessions. It basically has
>   two pieces of data, a player ID that is unique to your app as well as
>   the display name, that is what the user will have as what they want
>   they name to be displayed. This is not a GKPlayer object at all.
>
> If you try to use this for a leaderboard, for achievements, for other
>   multiplayer, for anything else, it will not work. So please don't do
>   that.
>
> Everyone will be very disappointed. So how do we get our Cloud
>   Players? Basically you can get your current signed in player.
>
> Most of the things in Sessions basically are going to be called from
>   your current player though there's not a whole lot of need to make
>   sure that you have the player, that you are then saying, "Oh, this
>   player is saving this data." All that's handled for you in the
>   background.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-611/?time=1139